# how to create a clocksignal for my fpga

Tags: vhdl, clock, xilinx

My question is simply as this i have a 200MHZ clock in my Xilinx sp605 board , and since my design can only run on 100Mhz i want input clock to be 100Mhz , so to achieve this :Will i have just to write clock value in UCF file and that's it or 
I have to create a VHDL component that takes 200Mhz and make it 100Mhz ?

Here is mu ucf file :

```
#  Spartan-6 SP605 Evaluation Platform
Net fpga_0_RS232_Uart_1_RX_pin LOC = H17  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_RS232_Uart_1_TX_pin LOC = B21  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<0> LOC=C18  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<1> LOC=Y6  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<2> LOC=W6  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<3> LOC=E4  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS15;
NET LED<0> LOC = "D17"; ## 2 on DS3 LED
NET LED<1> LOC = "AB4"; ## 2 on DS4 LED
NET LED<2> LOC = "D21"; ## 2 on DS5 LED
NET LED<3> LOC = "W15"; ## 2 on DS6 LED
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_clk_pin LOC=L20  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_clk_pin LOC=P20  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_crs_pin LOC=N15  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_dv_pin LOC=T22  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<0> LOC=P19  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<1> LOC=Y22  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<2> LOC=Y21  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<3> LOC=W22  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_col_pin LOC=M16  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_er_pin LOC=U20  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rst_n_pin LOC=J22  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25  |TIG;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_en_pin LOC=T8  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<0> LOC=U10  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<1> LOC=T10  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<2> LOC=AB8  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<3> LOC=AA8  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_MDC_pin LOC=R19  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_MDIO_pin LOC=V20  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_MDINT_pin LOC=J20  |IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25  |TIG;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<0> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<1> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<2> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<3> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<4> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<5> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<6> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<7> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<8> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<9> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<10> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<11> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<12> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ba_pin<0> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ba_pin<1> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ba_pin<2> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ras_n_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_cas_n_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_we_n_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_cke_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_clk_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_clk_n_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<0> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<1> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<2> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<3> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<4> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<5> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<6> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<7> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<8> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<9> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<10> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<11> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<12> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<13> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<14> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<15> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dqs_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dqs_n_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_udqs_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_udqs_n_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_udm_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ldm_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_odt_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ddr3_rst_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_rzq_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_zio_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_clk_1_sys_clk_p_pin TNM_NET = sys_clk_pin;
TIMESPEC TS_sys_clk_pin = PERIOD sys_clk_pin 200000 kHz;
Net fpga_0_clk_1_sys_clk_p_pin LOC = K21  |IOSTANDARD=LVDS_25  |DIFF_TERM = TRUE;
Net fpga_0_clk_1_sys_clk_n_pin LOC = K22  |IOSTANDARD=LVDS_25  |DIFF_TERM = TRUE;
Net fpga_0_rst_1_sys_rst_pin TIG;
Net fpga_0_rst_1_sys_rst_pin LOC = H8  |IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS15  |PULLUP  |TIG;
```

LOC K21 and k22 have been taken by microblaze and i cant use them , problem is even in the documentation i cant get global clock pins and thier frequency (btw i am referring to this documentation([Xilinx hardware desgin](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug526.pdf)) and also why is that EDK ucf file doesn't contain LOC of DDR3's pins ?? and it seems to work fine , does fpga figure it out on his own!?

Edit:
ok here this image is from plan ahead gui , it shows all I/O Ports in my spartan 6 now as u see all the hexagonal shapes are GCLK (Global clocks) that can be used as clocks to my design , problem is i dont know what is the frequency of each of this clocks!!
[image]

Comment: The SP605 Master UCF in that document shows all the DDR3 pins, named MEM1_* and their LOCs.

Comment: hmm, so it was a bug that edk created ucf file without ddr3 pins , but again how to get pins of Global clocks and their frequencies

Comment: @Omarshaaban - what do you mean "problem is i dont know what is the frequency of each of this clocks!!"?  Look at the schematic for the board and see what's connected there.  According to the user guide of the board there are a few clock nets routed out.  Two go to either an oscillator and a socket for an oscillator (feel free to dump whatever you want into the socket).  Otherwise you have SMA connectors.  Again: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug526.pdf.  Page 28.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't write your own clock divider.  You should use the internal DCM which can actually route to the global clock network.  An easy way to do this is use the coregen tools, which allow you to get use a template to instantiate the DCM.  You can divide, multiply, phase shift, etc your clock signal to almost anything within reason.  See the datasheet for details.  If you just divide the clock (by say using a flip flop) then you'll have really bad clock skew and are likely (almost guaranteed) to experience major timing headaches.  You want to take advantage of the fpga's clock routing network.

Comment: Can the DCM go as low as the 100kHz range? Honest question, never tested it. EDIT: Oh, the question was edited to 100MHz so more of an academic question now :)

Comment: ALL i want to know is what are locations of global pins and their frequency ..that's it the clocking resources documentation doesn't say anything about that , its all theoretical talk .....

Comment: @Omarshaaban Page 28 of the [pdf I linked in my answer](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug526.pdf) has info on which pins have which clock on that board.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson true those are 3 input clock signals available , but i wanted Global clock signals pins location and frequency , Spartan 6 has 16 global clocks that can be used and adjusted to clk frequency i think ...... i can see most of them using plan ahead gui but i am still looking into how to use them

Comment: @Omarshaaban  Look at the datasheet for the device.  It's all listed right there.  You start with http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds160.pdf. Very clearly you can click on the link for for clocking resources datasheet.  Then in the link that both Joachim and I posted you go to page 25 and there you have all the information you're trying to find.  It is *not* -as you say- all theoretical talk.  Page 25: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug382.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write a prescaler to divide the clock by 2. (or possibly 2000 since the frequency of the SP605 clock is *200MHz*, not *200kHz*)

The value in the UCF file is only telling ISE the frequency of your existing external clock, it does not generate that frequency for you automatically.

Comment: so using the timing contraints and choosing the frequency do nothing....hmm strange since i only have 1 200khz clock

Comment: @Omarshaaban There seem to be a few clocking options on the SP605, I'm no expert on that board so you're probably better off checking out chapter 7 of [this manual](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug526.pdf). There seems to be the option to put your own clock source in a socket.

Comment: It seems actually when I type in ucf file manually or using time constraint that i want a clock of 10MHZ foe example it will make one of the global clock lines to produce that frequency is that true ?
Btw by searching i knew that k21 and k22 are LOC OF 200mhz Clock but in the manual there is no say at all, i mean how is it called a manual when it doesn't even tell you location of your clock ?

Comment: No - when you set a clock frequency in the UCF you are telling the tools that is the frequency YOU will supply; the tools just make sure the design is fast enough for that speed (or report that they can't). You have to generate the right clock. There are blocks like DCM (Digital Clock Manager) that you can use to convert from e.g. 200MHz to 100MHz (don't know about kHz!)

Comment: Brian Drummond is correct.  Why are you using a SP605 for something that runs at 100 kHz?  What is running that slowly?  My guess is that you either mean MHz or that you should be using a faster clock (DCM at least on the spartan 3 can do a minimum frequency of a few MHz) with enable logic.  The user guide: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/ug526.pdf has all the information you're asking about including clock sources and pin locations on the FPGA.  Page 29 under the title "Clock Generation".  For information on constraints you should read the constraints guideline.

Comment: sorry was a big mistake , i means 200MHZ corrected it but didn't show on website(i guess i had bad connection) anyway i updated my post , i am looking on how to know what are my global clocks names and their frequency and also to know how does microblaze uses DDR3 when ddr3 pins locations are not in ucf file

Comment: Simply In my project i have my own vhdl code and also i am using a microblaze , now i implemented my vhdl code next to microblaze in the same vhdl top file , now microblaze clock input is directly from oscillator pin which is a 200MHZ clock and for my vhdl code i need a 100MHZ clock , so how from my 1 clock oscillator i can generate diffrent clock signals with different frequencies ?